# You're given the following list of numbers

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

You're given the following list of numbers:

> 10, 16, 20, 21, 22, 30, 32, 33, 34, 36, 41, 79, 82, 111, 148, 153

Hint 1:

> This question is correctly tagged; part of the puzzle is trying to figure out what type of puzzle it is.

Hint 2:

> The list has sixteen entries.

Hint 3:

> It's not a [number-sequence](/questions/tagged/number-sequence) puzzle, but the solution is definitely related.

Hint 4:

> The three largest numbers are related.

Hint 5:

> 41 is about two times 20.

Comment: To the downvoters: Please avoid downvoting without leaving a comment on why the post was downvoted.

Comment: I'm definitely not a downvoter, but most likely the downvotes come from the disregarding of the hint.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion this puzzle might receive a final edit *after* it is solved...! ;-)

Comment: @Stiv I can't read your mind but I do think you've found out what type of puzzle it is.

Comment: i think this might be a connect wall puzzle.

Comment: Glorfinder there are so many sequences I found that 2 numbers could fall into in a group of four...

Comment: Maybe I am going down a blind alley thinking that this is a connect wall.

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker that is often the case with connect walls.

Comment: The trouble with this puzzle Glorfindel is that connect walls often have variations that occur in the last step of the process... There is a lack of unanimity over what constitutes as a connection between the 4 groups. But I will give it a shot anyways

Answer (score 1):

Here is my guess:

> The numbers, when plotted on a number line, appear more clustered in some areas than others. This may be a hint to morse code.

> [image: plot]
>
>  The clusters appear to correspond to `..- -. - . ..` in morse code.
>  This spells `UNTEI` which can be rearranged to "UNITE" (or "untie")
>
>  UNITE makes sense as an answer since you must unite numbers to create the dashes in morse code.

Comment: With the anagram it's a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @riskymysteries Also the fact that sometimes there are 2 and another time 3 in a cluster makes me feel that it might not have been intended. It might not be completely off, though.

Comment: Nice try, but I'm thinking of something completely different. (I will post more hints if they are necessary.)